# java.util.Locale constructor does not workwhen using "gsw" as a Swiss language locale in Java 8

Tags: java, locale, jodatime

**The context**:

A customer asked me to help him with a method to format a Joda DateTime with a Locale specified as a parameter.

**The problem:**

Using "gsw" ([Swiss German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_German)) as a language does not seem to have an effect on the translation (falls back to English in my case).
"gsw" is part of ISO639-2 (which is ISO639 alpha-3, which the Java locale says it supports, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

I verified to be 100% sure and gsw is part of alpha-3, but it wasn't part of alpha-2 (ISO639-1): https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php
I've tried with other languages which are part of alpha-3 but were not present in alpha-2 and I see the same strange behavior.
Have I might not read well enough the Locale helpcenter?

**The code:** 
//all are types belong to joda.time, except Locale, which is java.util

```
DateTimeZone dtZone = DateTimeZone.forID(IANATimezone);
DateTime dtus = dateTime.withZone(dtZone);
Locale locale = new Locale(Language, Region);
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.fullDateTime().withLocale(locale);
```

Comment: You tag it as JodaTime? Do you use that or do you use `java.time`?

Comment: Also: just because a tag exist in the standard doesn't mean that every library will have the language resources for that library. Specifically I think JodaTime uses the JDKs default locale information for its data, so if that doesn't support `gsw` then you'll have to provide your own data.

Comment: I've started using JodaTime because this is part of a platform which used Joda classes for everything (built before Java 8). No reason to work it, I can do java.time, but your second comment is more interesting. I presumed that if a locale is part of the ISO 639 alpha2 and 3 , then translation would be offered within the runtime. Apparently this is not true?

Comment: It seems you are correct (let me know if what I'm thinking is right). Java 8 provides translations only for some of the languages, as explained here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk8-jre8-suported-locales.html.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, can you add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer? It seems this is the protocol based on posts similar to this one https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-the-answer-to-a-question